# PDF base64 string Filename

Tags: java, spring, rest, pdf

I have a doubt with a PDF base64 string, I don´t know why the filename is not appearing in the pdf viewer, instead of the filename I have a set of characters that I suppose are related with the byte array.

**Server side**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/report", produces = "application/pdf")
    public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<byte[]> reportPdf(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    ...
    byte[] document = report.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ...
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "pdf"));
    header.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=asdfasdfasdf.pdf");
    header.setContentLength(document.length);

    return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(document,header);
```

I´m calling this REST service throught JavaScript app and I don´t know what can I do to control this filename.

[image]

Could anyone give me any clue?. Could be possible change this new filename in this case?.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

It is safer to url encode the filename.

```
String fileName = "asdfasdfasdf.pdf";
URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "utf-8");
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType("application/pdf");
header.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

Or you may even try with put the file name in between double quotes `""`

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
header.setContentType("application/pdf");
header.set("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"asdfasdfasdf.pdf\"");
```

Comment: It doesn´t work, do you know if the header info are included inside the  data URI?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the workaround in something like this:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        //Setting up Jasper print
        JasperPrint print = getJasperPrint(REPORTS_PATH + reportPath, result, params);

        //Setting up Exporter configuration
        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration pdfExportConfiguration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
        pdfExportConfiguration.setMetadataTitle(title);

        //Setting up Jasper exporter
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
        exporter.setConfiguration(pdfExportConfiguration);

        //Exporting pdf
        exporter.exportReport();
enter code here
```

Using SimplePdfExporterConfiguration you are adding a extra info inside the report and for this reason the PDF viewer show the right name instead of the byte array code.